# as many as as much as

Tags: quantifiers

Which sentence is correct:

> 1. As many as 6% of US consumers say they are vegan, compared to just 1% in 2014. [source](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/02/06/health/vegan-how-to-food-drayer-wellness/index.html)
> 2. As much as 6% of US consumers say they are vegan, compared to just 1% in 2014.

I know that before percentages we put as much as, for example: Sales amount to as much as 40%.

Comment: Since the verb is _say_, and since it's plural, it should be _many_.

Answer (score 1):

**Much** is used with uncountable nouns, while **many** is used with countable nouns. The noun being modified is "consumers", who are countable, so **many** is correct.